# How to throw custom java exception in Android webview and catch it in JavaScript with custom message?

Tags: java, android, webview

I made custom JS interface for webview in android. When I throw exception:

```
@android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
public void aaa() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("aaa");
}
```

When I invoke it in javascript:

```
try {
   MyInterface.aaa();
} catch (e) {
   alert("e is " + (typeof e) + " = " + e);
}
```

I get "e is object = Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation". I get the same result when I throw custom java exception:

```
public static class IncorrectFileNameException extends Exception {
    public IncorrectFileNameException(String errorMessage) {
        super(errorMessage);
    }
}

@android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
public String aaa() throws Exception {
    throw new IncorrectFileNameException("custom");
}
```

The result is exactly the same: "e is object = Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation".

But in JavaScript I can throw custom message, e.g. throw "banana". Is it possible to make custom text for exception?

The problem is that now all exceptions are exactly the same which makes it hard to find the error.

Comment: I have a similar question. Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I did not find solution